# Why is my IDE marking this anonymous PHP function as a syntax error?

Tags: php, aptana3

I am using Aptana Studio (Aptana Studio 3 Version: 3.7.2.20180730) with a remote web server. Server has PHP version 5.5.59.

For some, possibly legitimate reason that is beyond me, my IDE is highlighting this anonymous function (Line 10) as a syntax error:

[image: Screenshot of syntax error in Aptana Studio.]

This is by far the biggest model I'm building so I'm hoping to get ahead of this if I need to take another approach. (I understand I can just make a generic validate function for the class, I'm considering it. For some reason, doing it this way appealed to me at the time.)

Comment: Property declarations can only take constant values (or immediately calculatable ones). Which would rule out anonymous functions

Comment: Thank you. Your comment is answer-worthy.